# PCB from washing machine, is it damaged?

Tags: pcb

I have simple question. Is it normal that coil attracts black dirt as you can see in the photo? Components seem to be good?
Thank you
Lukas

(Bosch washing machine PCB: AKO 547021-11)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What was the reason you took the washing machine apart?

Answer (score 5):

Does the washing machine still work?

I think this is rubber grit from the main belt operating the drum. It accumulates whereever there is a high electric field density. If it bothers you, blow it away with clean air.

Comment: It still works I suspect, but I concur, rubber has electrostatic insulation properties and is shown on both sides. while transformer creates alternating E field charges tend to accumulated to conductive frame which releases electrons freely with an E field of insulation in spite of AC fields.  I am not surprised they did not do accelerated life testing and I have seen a lot of trivial failures from design oversights on high end Bosch appliances.  Ask for Bosch for a free extended warranty on design flaws or recall notices and send photos.  (but then only HiV engineers are aware of this phenom)

Comment: This X must be part of their cost-reduced offline switcher power supply. and may get hotter slightly as rubber piles up, is All I would expect until bridged by moisture from a water leak then poof.

Comment: I think BSG should know it better because that circuit was in the washing machines they sold in the mid 1980ies, too. Still, it isn't the main failure cause of those machines. Most of them die a premature death because the heating pill for a bi-metal timer circuit controlling the door lock suddenly explodes. Can happen 2 years after buying or 10 years, but it happens. The replacement part costs as much as a Chinese washing machine does.

Comment: i see, considering all the automotive engineering experience they have, I guess cost reductions are good for sales. argh. to electromechanical stresses. I got tired of replacing coffee plate thermal fuses just below solder melting point and shunted both of them. All due to plate warp to heater interface and high Rth causing design flaws to creep in

Comment: Ah, BSH is neither Bosch nor Siemens. It's a 1980ies conglomerate of all near-bankrupt German household appliance manufacturers under the roof of "Bosch" and "Siemens". They aren't giving much more than the name. IIRC, infamous *Deutsche Bank* has introduced this, putting a line of damagers on the top of that company. That's the result.

Comment: There is only one thing which is not working.It is drum rotating (motor doesn't make any sound) . I checked all components (visually) and they look ok. Probably it is dust (i figured it out after I read your answers). I guess when I clean it up, it will look like a new PCB. I'll try check connection of a motor. Thank you

Comment: @kalu1: check the triac (the chip on the cooling plate) again. Most likely it is the only defective part. It's a BTA16CW-600, I think (but check it, maybe it's BTA16BW-800 or similar!) Get a replacement for this, costs about 1€+shipping. Worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, that looks like a total blowout. That is, an over-current or over-voltage failure on both the components and the traces on the underside of the board. I would check the to-220 package (the black thing attached to the heatsink) for visible damage and the Varistor (The blue thing to the right of the coil. They could be replaced, but you would also need to repair the PCB trace that blew out, which would be an argument to just replace the board all together. 
If I am incorrect however, that could be some sort of ferrous dust from a motor or shaft within the machine that is attracted to the electromagnetic emissions of that area of the circuit in particular.